# R smbinning package: why 'Too many categories' for some variables?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R containing many variables of different types and I am attempting to use the smbinning package to calculate Information Value.

I am using the following code:

```
smbinning.sumiv(Sample,y="flag")
```

This code produces IV for most of the variables, but for some the Process column states 'Too many categories' as shown in the output below:

```
                              Char     IV                Process
12                    relationship     NA    Too many categories
15                     nationality     NA    Too many categories
22               business_activity     NA    Too many categories
23         business_activity_group     NA    Too many categories
25                 local_authority     NA    Too many categories
26                   neighbourhood     NA    Too many categories
```

If I take a look at the values of business_activity_group for instance, I can see that there are not too many possible values it can take:

```
   Affordable Rent Combined Commercial Community Combined 
                     2546                             4 
     Freeholders Combined                       Garages 
                       23                             6 
   General Needs Combined                     Keyworker 
                    57140                           340 
       Leasehold Combined        Market Rented Combined 
                       88                          1463 
   Older Persons Combined               Rent To Homebuy 
                     4774                            76 
Shared Ownership Combined   Staff Acommodation Combined 
                      167                             5 
       Supported Combined 
                     2892
```

I thought this could be due to low volumes in some of the categories so I tried banding some of the groups together. This did not change the result.

Can anyone please explain why 'Too many categories' occurs, and what I can do to these variables in order to produce IV from the smbinning package?